# SQL Function compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL functions. I am trying to create a function as follows
Getting compilation error for the below SQL function.
Am I missing anything?

```
FUNCTION CANCEL_ORDER(INPUT_ORDER_ID T_ORDER_PLACEMENT.ORDER_ID%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER

 as
 ord_id NUMBER;

BEGIN

 SELECT order_id into ord_id from t_order_placement where ORDER_ID=INPUT_ORDER_ID;

EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUT.PUT_LINE('NO_DATA_FOUND');
END;

IF ord_id IS NOT NULL then
 Delete from t_order_details where ORDER_ID=INPUT_ORDER_ID
 Return 1;
Commit;
END IF;

EXCEPTION
WHEN ord_id IS NULL THEN DBMS_OUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');
END;
```

Even for the procedure also I am getting compilation error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS(CUSTOMER_ID IN NUMBER, CUSTOMER_DETAILS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS
    BEGIN
    OPEN CUSTOMER_DETAILS FOR
    select C.CUST_ID, C.CUST_NAME, OP.ORDER_ID, SD.STOCK_NAME, OD.QUANTITY from t_customer C, t_order_placement OP, t_order_details OD, t_stock_details SD
    END GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
```

Comment: The code is clearly Oracle, so I changed the tag.  If you are using MySQL, then learn the MySQL scripting language -- which is quite different from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd Procedurce (PROCEDURE GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS) is an ";" missing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS(CUSTOMER_ID IN NUMBER, CUSTOMER_DETAILS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS
    BEGIN
    OPEN CUSTOMER_DETAILS FOR
    select C.CUST_ID, C.CUST_NAME, OP.ORDER_ID, SD.STOCK_NAME, OD.QUANTITY from t_customer C, t_order_placement OP, t_order_details OD, t_stock_details SD;
    END GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `BEGIN`, missing semicolon after `DELETE`, `DBMS_OUT` should be `DBMS_OUTPUT`, last exception is impossibly to happen. Consider using foreign key with option `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

In the procedure - missing semicolon after `SELECT` statement.

```
function cancel_order(input_order_id t_order_placement.order_id%type)
    return number as

    ord_id number;

begin

    begin
        select order_id into ord_id 
            from t_order_placement 
            where order_id = input_order_id;
    exception when no_data_found then 
        dbms_output.put_line('no_data_found');
        return 0;
    end;

    delete from t_order_details where order_id = input_order_id;

    -- commit;   -- <-- commit here if needed

    return 1;

end;
```